# Can I use Invoke-WebRequest to write binary data to a file and still get the status code?

Tags: powershell, download

I need to download a file using a POST request, however, since PowerShell seemingly can't handle binary data in pipes and variables (`Out-File` doesn't support binary data), I need to use the `-OutFile` parameter of `Invoke-WebRequest`. When doing this, however, it no longer outputs the status code so that I can capture it in a variable:

```bsh
PS K:\hmpf> $Filepath = "E:\shmimpf\g\yyv.fgr"
PS K:\hmpf> $URL = "https://wwwh.ipswich.org/tycobrahe/magazine.php?burgerflipcount=76"
PS K:\hmpf> (Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $URL -OutFile $Filepath -Method Post).StatusCode
PS K:\hmpf> (Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $URL -Method Post).StatusCode
200
PS K:\hmpf>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [documentation for `Invoke-WebRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest#parameters):

> ```
> -PassThru
>
>     Indicates that the cmdlet returns the results, in addition to writing them to a file. 
>     This parameter is valid only when the OutFile parameter is also used in the command.
> ```

So to get the response results in conjunction with `-OutFile`:

```bsh
(Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $URL -OutFile $Filepath -Method Post -PassThru).StatusCode
```